How to load JS react first on WordPress website to resolve the CLS issue?
My WordPress site with the Kadence premium theme is experiencing a CLS issue on Google. I suspect a React plugin is causing this, but it needs to load before the rest of the page. There’s a noticeable page flash before loading.
If you load the website you can flush off the page before actually loading the Test screen tool. Please also review the Fake screen page, which has a similar issue.
I am using Astra child theme and WP-Rocket plugin.
Note: I also enable the preload option with WP-Rocket, but its still showing a flash of text before the actual tool loading.
Thanks
To resolve my website issue.
